# Bind Exception only when launched at boot [Raspbian]

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, serversocket, boot

I'm launching a java program during my Raspberry startup (which is turning on Raspbian).
I used the `/etc/rc.local` file to do this and **it works properly** (I also tried /etc/init.d/ solution but I prefer the other one).
I'm launching my raspbian directly on console mode, this way I can see my program's output.

My problem is : **Manually starting my app, it works well. Starting automatically at boot, it raise a Bind Exception : Can't assign requested address.**

## Launching the program

On the **/etc/rc.local** file, I wrote this line. It launch a script which start my .jar program.

```
#! /bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# [...]

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
    printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
# \/ Added \/
/home/pi/Documents/DinnerTimePi/startApp

exit 0
```

My **startApp** script contains :

```
#! /bin/sh

cd /home/pi/Documents/DinnerTimePi/

date >> testStart.txt #Only for checking it runs at launch
java -jar DinnerTimeServer.jar

exit 0
```

## Normal program output

```
Server initialised at : 192.168.1.35 address and : 35150 port.
_ #(Waiting for client to connect)
```

## Java program part

My Java program is a ServerSocket doing some stuff, it works properly too.

```
public class TimeServer {
    //Instance of class : can have only one server at a time
    static private TimeServer instance;
    //Default values
    static private int port = 35150;
    static private String host = "192.168.1.35"; //Adapt for your network, give a fix IP by DHCP
    //Variables
    private ServerSocket server = null;


    protected TimeServer(String pHost, int pPort){ // <- I'm running this constructor with the default values above
        list = new LinkedList<ClientProcessor>();
        host = pHost; // 192.168.1.135
        port = pPort; // 35150
        try {
            // \/ Line 57 on my code (see stack trace) \/
            server = new ServerSocket(port, 10, InetAddress.getByName(host));
        } catch (BindException bind){
            bind.printStackTrace(); //Here is the problem !!
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (UnknownHostException hoste) {
            hoste.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

As you can see, I used the IP address 192.168.1.35, which is **static** on my modem, and it works well. 
I supposed the port was used during the boot, so **I tried different ports**, as 6543 and 35150. But it does the same thing : working manually, but not working during auto startup.

## Stack trace

This is what I see as output when booting my Raspberry.

```
[...]
[ OK ] Reached target Network is Online.
       Starting LSB: Start NTP deamon...
[ OK ] Started LSB: Start NTP deamon.
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at server.TimeServer.<init>(TimeServer.java:57)
    at server.TimeServer.getInstance(TimeServer.java:32)
    at server.Main_Server.main(Main_Server.java:12)
[ OK ] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
       Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
[...]
```

**The thing I don't understand is why my program works well launching it by myself, and it doesn't when the system launch it.**
There is **no root needs** for my program.

I hope it is clear, don't hesitate if you need more informations.

Thanks for help ! :)

(Check out the entire program if needed on [github](https://github.com/Kapcash/DinnerTimePi), **autolaunch branch**)

Comment: You are using InetAddress.getByName(host) which needs name resolution to be working (and perhaps it's not at the point when you call the function), but you already know the IP address, so InetAddress.forString(String ipString) would be more appropriate.

Comment: I don't know where you saw your method, according to the documentation, it doesn't exist ^^"
It works well like this, even if I agree with you, I don't give the host name but directly the IP java is searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw the lines of the constructor into a specific function:

```
protected boolean initThis(String pHost, int pPort) {
    list = new LinkedList<ClientProcessor>();
    host = pHost; // 192.168.1.135
    port = pPort; // 35150
    try {
        // \/ Line 57 on my code (see stack trace) \/
        server = new ServerSocket(port, 10, InetAddress.getByName(host));
    } catch (BindException bind){
        bind.printStackTrace(); //Here is the problem !!
        return false;
    } catch (UnknownHostException hoste) {
        hoste.printStackTrace();
        return false; // Change this to true if you want it to stop here
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return false; // Change to true to stop here
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now in your constructor:

```
protected TimeServer(String pHost, int pPort) {
    while(!initThis(pHost, pPort))
        Thread.sleep(500); // Wait 0.5 secs before retry
}
```

This will retry so many times until it works.

Comment: I can't believe it. I never thought a second it would be the problem because it works perfectly manually. This solution is so simple ! 
Thanks a lot, you save me.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that this helps you. Thanks for reporting.